# WiFi connection issues - Ventura on 14" 2021 m1 pro

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, ventura

I have a 2021 14" m1 pro running Ventura 13.0.1. Recently, I noticed that my home WiFi sometimes suddenly stops working. I'm using Firefox with ublock origin. For about 30 seconds, all sites would be "not found", and `ping google.com` would give nothing. Other browsers like Chrome and Safari would also give nothing, i.e. "not found".

The WiFi icon on the top bar does not become a "disconnected" icon or anything like that. Even clicking into the WiFi menu does not show anything wrong.

While this is happening, my iPhone 13 and 11 inch iPad Pro would both have WiFi working fine. None of my other devices in my home have WiFi issues either, while my macbook's WiFi momentarily is broken this way.

The network I'm connected to is my Optimum router, which has a WiFi network named _5g.

I only started noticing this issue on my Macbook recently, a bit after I updated to Ventura. Before this, my WiFi worked fine.

Update: The exact same behavior seems to also be happening on my work laptop, which is the exact same model of Macbook pro and same Ventura version.

Comment: Define "stop working" -- do you mean you lose connection, or just that things are really slow? If you hold Alt and click on the Wifi menulet, you should get more info, including transmission speed. Also, what happens if you use Safari, or turn off ublock?

Comment: For about 30 seconds, all sites would be "not found", and ping google.com would give nothing.

Comment: Does the Wifi icon in the menubar or Control Center display as connected, or unconnected when this happens?

Comment: good question; none of the icons show anything wrong. I just updated my question.